# Iterate over several (but not all) columns in a data frame with purrr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I am looking for a laconic way to work with several columns at once inside a tidyverse pipe.
The problem is that I don't need to work with all columns: only several.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column(var = 'car')
str(mtcars)

'data.frame':   32 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ car : chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Imagine I wanted to perform some action with columns `drat`, `qsec` and `gear`. (For example, convert to character. who knows why)

How can one do it without writing the action 3 times? Perhaps using `purrr()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 key functions here are `map_at` (or `map_if` if instead of knowing the columns, we know something about the columns but don't know which ones we need) and `map_df` (which returns a data frame instead of a list).

Unfortunately, I can't see a function that combines both. But we can work around it. Looking under the hood on `map_df`, it is a regular `map` with added `bind_rows()` in the end.

So that's all we need:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  map_at(c('drat', 'qsec', 'gear'), as.character) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: You're looking for `modify_at`, The idea of the `map` family of function is to have a fixed output, the idea of the `modify` family is to have the same format for output and input. In this case `mutate_at` will work fine too (I think `modify_at` and `mutate_at` behave identically on data.frames, but the `mutate` family works only on data.frames)

Answer (score 2):

Try `mutate_at` in dplyr:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(c("drat", "qsec", "gear"), as.character)
```

It can also be written like this:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(drat, qsec, gear), as.character)
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution. We can use `lapply` to loop through the column names and design a function to convert the target columns to character.

```
mtcars[] <- lapply(colnames(mtcars),
                    function(x) {
                      y <- mtcars[[x]]
                      if (x %in% c("drat", "qsec", "gear")){
                        y <- as.character(y)
                      }
                      return(y)
                    })

str(mtcars)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  12 variables:
#   $ car : chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
# $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# $ drat: chr  "3.9" "3.9" "3.85" "3.08" ...
# $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# $ qsec: chr  "16.46" "17.02" "18.61" "19.44" ...
# $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ gear: chr  "4" "4" "4" "3" ...
# $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Comment: I am pretty sure there a base R solution. But just as I thought, it's a bit more cumbersome than its tidyverse counterpart. IMO.

Comment: Yes, I agree. mutate_at and map_at are more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `modify` or `modify_at` from `purrr`, `modify` functions are like `map` except that the output is formatted like the input.

`modify_at` will be used in the same way as `mutate_at` in @g-grothendieck's solution:

```
mtcars %>% modify_at(c("drat", "qsec", "gear"), as.character)
```

If you use `magrittr` you could also do this (this one overwrites `mtcars`):

```
mtcars[, c("drat", "qsec", "gear")] %<>% modify(as.character)
```